# Visual Studio code inspection like in Rider

Tags: c#, visual-studio, analysis, inspection

How can I display inline compiler warnings in VS? Visual Studio shows compiler errors inline, but not warnings.

In Rider:
[image: Rider]

In Visual Studio:
[image: Visual Studio]

AS you can see, there's a clear possible nullreference, which is easy to see, but Visual Studio doesn't warn me

Comment: That doesn't come free with VS, AFAIK. There are extensions for that kind of functionality though.

Comment: Works for me. I have Resharper installed, though, and maybe that's the reason.

Comment: Works for me without plugins. Have you enabled nullable?

Comment: @PMF Yep, installed ReSharper and the squiggly lines appeared

Comment: @shingo what color are the underlines? Mine are blue now that I've installed ReSharper.
If I uninstall ReSharper, the warnings disappear. Are you sure you don't have it installed?

Comment: @shredder I use the blue theme so the underlines are green. It's 2022 incidentally.

Comment: Yep, should've figured that they depend on the color. I use Rider Dark and also VS 2022